# Need explanation for proving two sigma algebra are same.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove this theorem.

> Let $C$ be any collection of subsets of a set $X$. Let $A(C)$ the
> algebra generated by $C$. Prove that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by
> $C$ and $A(C)$ are the same.

I have read the proof in [Prove that the two $\sigma$-algebra are the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607698/prove-that-the-two-sigma-algebra-are-the-same), but there are several part of prove which I don't understand.

The idea of prove is proving $\sigma(C)=\sigma(A(C))$, so we prove $\sigma(C)\subset \sigma(A(C))$ and $\sigma(A(C))\subset \sigma(C)$.

> Proving $\sigma(C)\subset \sigma(A(C))$.
>
> Since $C\subset A(C)$ and $A(C)\subset\sigma [A(C)]$ then $C\subset
>  \sigma [A(C)]$. $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
> containing $C$ thus $\sigma(C)\subset\sigma [A(C)]$.

Why if $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$ then $\sigma(C)\subset\sigma [A(C)]$?

I know if $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$ then $C\subset \sigma (C)$. Now we have $C\subset \sigma (C)$ and $C\subset \sigma [A(C)]$. Why he/she can conclude $\sigma(C)\subset\sigma [A(C)]$?

> Proving $\sigma(A(C))\subset \sigma(C)$
>
> For the other way, note that $C\subset \sigma(C)$. Since $\sigma(C)$
> is also an algebra thus $A(C)\subset \sigma(C)$.   $\sigma [A(C)]$ is
> the smallest algebra containing $[A(C)]$ thus $\sigma [A(C)]\subset
>  \sigma(C)$.

Is this wrong proof? "$\sigma [A(C)]\subset \sigma(C)$" means $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest algebra containing $\sigma [A(C)]$.

Comment: $\sigma(C)$ is the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$, and $\sigma[A(C)]$ is one $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$…

Comment: Also if $A$ contains $B$ then $\sigma(A)$ contains $\sigma(B)$.